# sharing a control between two tab control in ASPX/C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, visual-studio, web-frontend

I need to change an exising ASPX page by adding a tab control. This will change the layout and so I have started with this tag:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 500px; padding: 10px; margin: 10px">
    <div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TAB 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content" style="padding-top: 20px">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                This is Tab 1
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
               This is Tab 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to insert a  control for tab panel. How can I share it and modify it on the fly during swtich from one tab to another tab?

I will appreciate it.
Thanks.

p.s. I'm not an expert in this so are there better ways or sample that you could share?

Comment: What is content of that tab that will be loaded "on-the-fly" ?

Comment: <asp:GridView> will be used on each panel.